# Nav-bar not responding to click

Tags: html, css

I'm having issues with making my nav-bar responsive because when the browser is reduced to a smaller size. The nav-bar image does not respond when clicked. Would like your help in this as I'm not so great in front-end development. Here is the code. I have placed a comment on the place of issue.

[image]
**BASE HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'student/main.css' %}">

    {% if title %}
        <title>LNTU {{ title }}</title>
    {% else %}
        <title>LNTU</title>
    {% endif %}
</head>
<body>
    <header class="site-header">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-steel fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
          <a class="navbar-brand mr-4" href="{% url 'student-home' %}">LNTU</a>
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarToggle" aria-controls="navbarToggle" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarToggle">
            <div class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
              
            </div>

            
        </article>
            <!-- Navbar Right Side -->
            <div class="navbar-nav">
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{% url 'student-home' %}">Home</a>
              {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{% url 'profile' %}">Profile</a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{% url 'logout' %}">Logout</a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{% url 'password_change' %}">Change Password</a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{% url 'profile-update' %}">Update Profile</a>
              {% else %}
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{% url 'login' %}">Login</a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{% url 'register' %}">Register</a>
              {% endif %}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </header>
    <main role="main" class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
          {% if messages %}
            {% for message in messages %}
              <div class="alert alert-{{ message.tags }}">
                {{ message }}
              </div>
            {% endfor %}
          {% endif %}
          {% block content %}
          
        
          
          {% endblock %}
        </div>
      <!-- <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="content-section">
            <h3>Our Sidebar</h3>
            <p class='text-muted'>You can put any information here you'd like.
              <ul class="list-group">
                <li  class="list-group-item list-group-item-light">Latest Posts</li>
                <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-light">Announcements</li>
                <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-light">Calendars</li>
                <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-light">etc</li>
              </ul>
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>-->

        <!--image generic profile-->
        <!-- <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="content-section">
            <img class="img-thumbnail account-img" src="{{ user.information.image.url }}">
          </div>
        </div>-->
      </div>
    </main>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    background: #fafafa;
    color: #333333;
    margin-top: 5rem;
  }
  
  h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    color: #444444;
  }
  
  ul {
    margin: 0;
  }
  
  .bg-steel {
    background-color: #5f788a;
  }
  
  .site-header .navbar-nav .nav-link {
    color: #cbd5db;
  }
  
  .site-header .navbar-nav .nav-link:hover {
    color: #ffffff;
  }
  
  .site-header .navbar-nav .nav-link.active {
    font-weight: 500;
  }
  
  .content-section {
    background: #ffffff;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    border-radius: 3px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }
  
  .article-title {
    color: #444444;
  }
  
  a.article-title:hover {
    color: #428bca;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  
  .article-content {
    white-space: pre-line;
  }
  
  .article-img {
    height: 65px;
    width: 65px;
    margin-right: 16px;
  }
  
  .article-metadata {
    padding-bottom: 1px;
    margin-bottom: 4px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e3e3e3
  }
  
  .article-metadata a:hover {
    color: #333;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  
  .article-svg {
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    vertical-align: middle;
  }
  
  .account-img {
    height: 125px;
    width: 125px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 16px;
  }
  
  .account-heading {
    font-size: 2.5rem;
  }
```

Comment: you have inserted an incorrect css. Look at the very top of your css.

Comment: @sergeykuznetsov I have corrected the issue, it was a mistake on my part when asking the question, please do you have a solution to proffer?

Answer (score 0):

You can change code to something like this.

```html
<header class="site-header">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-steel fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
          <a class="navbar-brand mr-4" href="{% url 'student-home' %}">LNTU</a>
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarToggle" aria-controls="navbarToggle" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarToggle">
          
            <!-- Navbar Right Side -->
            <div class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{% url 'student-home' %}">Home</a>
              {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{% url 'profile' %}">Profile</a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{% url 'logout' %}">Logout</a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{% url 'password_change' %}">Change Password</a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{% url 'profile-update' %}">Update Profile</a>
              {% else %}
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{% url 'login' %}">Login</a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{% url 'register' %}">Register</a>
              {% endif %}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </header>
```

Also check bootstrap docs https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/navbar/ for details.